# How i can get sessionid from this SOAPXML

Tags: php, xml, soap, xml-parsing

I want to get sessionid from this XML piece of code:

```
<soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:header>
     <soapenv:body>
       <p725:loginresponse xmlns:p725="http://www.fleetboard.com/data">
         <p725:loginresponse sessionid="0001nABbah-I8f75oDrVbHrBgOv:s96fb0a4m3"></p725:loginresponse>
        </p725:loginresponse>
     </soapenv:body>
   </soapenv:header>
 </soapenv:envelope>
```

I have tried this but this doesn't work:

```
$soap=simplexml_load_string($result);
$xml_response = $soap->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body()->children()->p725;
echo $session_id =  (int) $xml_response->session_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.  The first is as you are currently doing it, but this involves various changes of namespace and means you need to keep on getting the right child elements and the attribute itself...

```
$soap=simplexml_load_string($result);
$xml_response = $soap->children("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")->header->body;
$session_id = $xml_response->children("http://www.fleetboard.com/data")->loginresponse->loginresponse;
echo $session_id->attributes()->sessionid.PHP_EOL;
```

Or you can use XPath, where you will need to register the namespace with the document first and then select the `loginresponse` element with a `sessionid` element.  This will return a list of matches, so you have to take the first one using `[0]`...

```
$soap=simplexml_load_string($result);
$soap->registerXPathNamespace("p725", "http://www.fleetboard.com/data");
$session_id = $soap->xpath("//p725:loginresponse/@sessionid");
echo $session_id[0];
```

Comment: Not sure what that means - are you getting any errors, or any data?

Comment: no i am getting blank data
i need to get the sessionid from this xml

Comment: With the sample XML you provided in your question and either set of code above it outputs `0001nABbah-I8f75oDrVbHrBgOv:s96fb0a4m3`.